# Select where field contains specific item and any other

Tags: sql

Say I have the following table

```
ID | Trans_id 
1  | 10
2  | 20 
2  | 20
2  | 20
2  | 20
2  | 10
3  | 20
4  | 20
5  | 10
6  | 10
```

How do I select the ID where trans_id contains 20 *and* has another different number, no matter what it is (in this example, I should return ID 2 only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when trans_id = 20 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when trans_id <> 20 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `exists`

```
Select distinct Id from table t
Where trans_id = 20
   and exists (Select * from table 
               Where ID = t.Id
                  and trans_id != 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Trans_id = 20)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Trans_id)) > 1
```

The subquery only selects ID's which contain `Trans_id = 20`, the `GROUP BY ID` + `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Trans_id)) > 1` ensures that there are other Trans_id's in this group.

Answer (score -1):

That will work:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM MyTable WHERE Trans_id = 20
```

Comment: No, it wont. In OP's sample it will return `2, 3, 4`, 3 and 4 are incorrect because there are no other Trans_ID's